# How to use a regexp to replace each item in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm a beginner with javascript, and after searching I am still running into an error with this part of my code.

I have an array:

```
var choices = [ '$5/hr', '$6/hr', '$7/hr', '$10/hr' ];
```

And I want to use a regular expression to return the array as integers so I can use it for further calculations. I know that `replace` only works on strings and not an array so I have tried the following:

```
// Strip other characters and return only integers.
for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    choices[i] = choices[i].replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
}
```

EDIT: Apparently the issue is somewhere else in my code. Maybe this needs to be wrapped in another function?

Here is the function that this resides in. This function receives an array as a value and will calculate an average using the array received and the choices array which I cannot convert to integers.

```
        // Choice values
        var ul = document.getElementById('Results');
        var choices = [];

        //  Get li element choices
        for (var i = 0; i < ul.childNodes.length; i++) {
            if (ul.childNodes[i].nodeName == "LI") {
                choices.push(ul.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
        // Strip the last element in array since it is the result container.
        choices.splice(-1,1);

        // Strip other characters and return only integers.
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            choices[i] = choices[i].replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not getting such exception. tested in firefox mozilla/chrome.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8dsru/

Comment: How do you call on the function that contains this for loop, I'd wager that the issue is how you call it with the error: "undefined is not a function"

Comment: Hm, okay thanks, must be an issue somewhere else. I will paste in more of my code.

Comment: the issue in in Chrome and IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are pushing the nodes in your array, not their text content. Try this instead:

```
choices.push(ul.childNodes[i].textContent)
```

or:

```
choices.push(ul.childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
```

Comment: Thanks @Christophe ! This does seem to be the solution and you helped me realize that I am selecting the child li elements when I should be selecting the label elements inside each list. 

Could you tell me how I could modify `if (ul.childNodes[i].nodeName == "LI") {` to select from label elements inside those lists? IE: ul>li>label, not ul>li. Thank you!

Comment: Could you post your html? Even better, could you post it on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: You could simply use: `var labels=ul.getElementsByTagName("label");`

Comment: Got it. You are right. Thanks!

`for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {choices.push(ul.getElementsByTagName('label')[i].innerHTML);}`